# When creating a directive programmatically with $compile, how do you call the link function?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I'm creating a directive within another parent directive and then appending the directive's compiled element to the parent directive's node.  $compile(template)(scope) correctly creates the directive, but the link function is not being called.

```
var addProductsToPage = function(template, products) {

      for (var i = 0 ; i < products.length ; i++) {

        var product = products[i];

        var productScope = $scope.$new(true);

        productScope.product = product

        var productDirective = $compile(template);

        var productElement = productDirective(productScope);

        element.append(productElement);

      }

}
```

How do I call the link function after I compile the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$compile(template)` actually returns the link function.

So `productDirective(productScope)` is actually the call to the link function.

Source : [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

> **Returns** {function(scope[, cloneAttachFn])} – a link function which is
>   used to bind template (a DOM element/tree) to a scope

Comment: Yeah if you take a look I'm calling the link function.  It's properly applying the scope, but it's not actually firing my link function.

Comment: @JesseEarle how did you resolve this problem? The answer was marked as right.